# Gitlab CPU cycle issue

Tags: linux, gitlab

We have gitlab server for our company. gitlab.xxx.com; sometimes site going down. while cheking the cpu and memory usage and found that git is taking more usage

git  20   0 1170352 548808  20688 R  (CPU 92.2)  1.7   6:07.97 bundle

git is taking 97% usage

is there anything wrong in this?

Regards
pandian

Comment: Post full git command that is running. My bet is on repack.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I have the same problem
@JakubKania What's repack?

Comment: @Chumillas https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack It''s a maintence operation that runs every X commits and back then didn't have an option to schedule it as a cron job, not sure about now.